# Duplicates on Apache Beam / Dataflow inputs even when using withIdAttribute

Tags: duplicates, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to ingest data from a 3rd party API into a Dataflow pipeline. Since the 3rd party doesn't make webhooks available, I wrote a custom script that constantly polls their endpoint for more data.

The data is refreshed every 15 minutes, but since I don't want to miss any datapoints and I want to consume as soon as new data is available, my "crawler" runs every 1 minute. The script then sends the data to a PubSub topic. Easy to see that PubSub will receive about 15 repeated messages for each datapoint in the source.

My first attempt to identify and discard those repeated messages was to add a custom attribute to each PubSub message (`eventid`), created from a hash of its [ID + updated_time] at source.

```js
const attributes = {
         eventid: Buffer.from(`${item.lastupdate}|${item.segmentid}`).toString('base64'),
         timestamp: item.timestamp.toString()
      };
const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(item))
publisher.publish(dataBuffer, attributes)
```

Then I configured Dataflow with a [`withIdAttribute()`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.Read.html#withIdAttribute-java.lang.String-) (which is the new `idLabel()`, based on [Record IDs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io#using-record-ids)).

```java
PCollection<String> input = p
    .apply("ReadFromPubSub", PubsubIO
       .readStrings()
       .fromTopic(String.format("projects/%s/topics/%s", options.getProject(), options.getIncomingDataTopic()))
       .withTimestampAttribute("timestamp")
       .withIdAttribute("eventid"))
   .apply("OutputToBigQuery", ...)
```

With that implementation, I was expecting that when the script sends the same datapoint a second time, the repeated `eventid` would be the same and the message discarded. But for some reason, I still see duplicates on the output dataset.

Some questions:

1. Is there a clever way to ingest the data to dataflow from that 3rd party API if they don't provide webhooks?
2. Any ideas on why dataflow is not discarding the messages on this situation?

   - I know about the 10-minute restriction for deduplication on dataflow, but I see duplicated data even on the 2nd insertion (2 minutes).

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not quite sure about the guarantees that pubsub gives around eventid, but you must be able to deduplicate with a GroupByKey operation, or using stateful operations

Comment: Hm, didn't think about the GroupByKey as a way to deduplication. If I'm expecting to receive these doubled data for 15 minutes, it means I need a window of at least this amount of time, so that a group can eliminate all duplicates, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track, instead of the hash I recommend to use timestamps. A better way to to this is by using windows. Review this [document](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/mobile-gaming-example/#what-does-hourlyteamscore-do) which filters data that is outside of the window.

Regarding the additional duplicate data, if you are using pull subscriptions and the acknowledgement deadline is reached before having the data processed the message will be resent as per the [at-least-once delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery). In this case change the acknowledgement deadline, the defaults is 10 seconds.